# Automatic Fence Lighting with Alarm

Tags: transistors, analog, bjt

The circuit below has a BC557 transistor (Q1). Is this transistor functioned as a switch?

[image]

Comment: Yes, it is acting as a switch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**U1** acts more as the switch, since it is running at maximum open-loop gain, which is greater than about 20,000. It is unlikely that U1's output voltage will be found near the mid-way point of the 9V DC supply: it will either be saturated near ground, or up near +9V when **LDR1** is illuminated.

Q1 has no voltage gain - it is acting more as a buffer, and it also adds a small DC offset, so that the LED is off while the **LDR1** is illuminated.